# Identifying memory addresses

Tags: c, memory, linux-kernel, ram, kernel-module

I want to build a kernel module to read memory (ram) addresses content after the reboot. How can I identify the memory addresses or ranges that I can read and are not used by the system.

- CPU: 64bit-ARMv8-A RAM: 4 GB

My code:

```
 #include <linux/module.h>   
 #include <linux/kernel.h>  


         int init_module(void)
         {

             long start_addr;
             long end_addr;


             long  *i;
             long  *start; 
             long  *end ;

             start_addr = 0xffffffbffc00201c; //
             end_addr = 0xffffffbffc00303c; // 

           start= (long*)start_addr ;
           end= (long*)end_addr;

           for(i=start ; i <= end ; i++ ){

               printk(KERN_ALERT "\nThe  Address = 0x%p\n", i);
               printk(KERN_ALERT "\nThe  content = %lx\n", *i);
                 }
        return 0;
      }

     void cleanup_module(void)
     {
       printk(KERN_ALERT "Goodbye world 1.\n");
     }
```

Comment: Are you looking for what addresses are marked as accessible that are allocated to  other processes and are accessible from all processes ?

Comment: All addresses are virtual except when mapping for a specific device.  Unused virtual addresses will fault when read.

Comment: The aim is to study ram startup value behavior in order to build either DRAM-Based random number generation or DRAM-Based PUF.